# RabbitMQ and Spark Streaming Error Connection Refused

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rabbitmq, spark-streaming

I am trying to connect to a remote RabbitMQ service (which I have tested for connectivity using a separate python code), using Spark Streaming. I'm using a custom receiver in this way:

```
import com.rabbitmq.client._
import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Connection;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;
import com.rabbitmq.client.QueueingConsumer;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.rabbitmq.RabbitMQUtils
import java.io.{BufferedReader, InputStreamReader}
import java.net.Socket
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}
import org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.{InputDStream, ReceiverInputDStream}
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver._
import org.apache.spark.internal.Logging


object CustomReceiverUT {
        def main(args: Array[String]) {


                //RabbitMQ things
                val host = "1.2.3.4"
                val port = "5672"
                val queueName = "Test_Wave"
                val vHost = "/"
                val userName = "mhadmin"
                val password = "password"


                //Configure Spark properties
                val sparkConfig = new SparkConf()
                  .setAppName("Spark-Stream-Test")
                  .setIfMissing("spark.master", "local[*]")

                val ssc =  new StreamingContext(sparkConfig, Seconds(5))

                val receiverStream = RabbitMQUtils.createStream(ssc, Map(
                        "host" -> host,
                        "port" -> port,
                        "queueName" -> queueName,
                        "vHost" -> vHost,
                        "userName" -> userName,
                        "password" -> password
                ))

                val totalEvents = ssc.sparkContext.longAccumulator("My Accumulator")

                receiverStream.start()
                println("started receiverStream")

                 receiverStream.foreachRDD(rdd => {
                      if (!rdd.isEmpty()) {
                        val count = rdd.count()
                           // Do something with this message
                                println(s"EVENTS COUNT : \t $count")
                                totalEvents.add(count)
                          //rdd.collect().sortBy(event => event.toInt).foreach(event => print(s"$event, "))
                   } else println("RDD is empty")
                                println(s"TOTAL EVENTS : \t $totalEvents")
                })


                ssc.start()
                ssc.awaitTermination()
}
}
```

However, when I run this code, I keep getting a connection refused error:

```
17/06/27 16:04:47 INFO ReceiverSupervisorImpl: Starting receiver 0
17/06/27 16:04:47 ERROR RabbitMQReceiver: Could not connect
17/06/27 16:04:47 INFO ReceiverSupervisorImpl: Called receiver 0 onStart
17/06/27 16:04:47 INFO ReceiverSupervisorImpl: Waiting for receiver to be stopped
17/06/27 16:04:47 WARN ReceiverSupervisorImpl: Restarting receiver with delay 2000 ms: Could not connect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandlerFactory.create(SocketFrameHandlerFactory.java:50)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.newConnection(RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.java:60)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringConnection.init(AutorecoveringConnection.java:99)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:911)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:870)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:692)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.rabbitmq.consumer.Consumer$.org$apache$spark$streaming$rabbitmq$consumer$Consumer$$addConnection(Consumer.scala:269)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.rabbitmq.consumer.Consumer$$anonfun$1.apply(Consumer.scala:251)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.rabbitmq.consumer.Consumer$$anonfun$1.apply(Consumer.scala:251)
        at scala.collection.MapLike$class.getOrElse(MapLike.scala:128)
        at scala.collection.AbstractMap.getOrElse(Map.scala:59)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.rabbitmq.consumer.Consumer$.getChannel(Consumer.scala:251)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.rabbitmq.consumer.Consumer$.apply(Consumer.scala:207)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.rabbitmq.receiver.RabbitMQReceiver$$anonfun$3.apply(RabbitMQInputDStream.scala:60)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.rabbitmq.receiver.RabbitMQReceiver$$anonfun$3.apply(RabbitMQInputDStream.scala:59)
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.rabbitmq.receiver.RabbitMQReceiver.onStart(RabbitMQInputDStream.scala:59)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.startReceiver(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:149)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.start(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverTrackerEndpoint$$anonfun$9.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:597)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverTrackerEndpoint$$anonfun$9.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:587)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$33.apply(SparkContext.scala:1976)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$33.apply(SparkContext.scala:1976)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
17/06/27 16:04:47 INFO ReceiverSupervisorImpl: Stopping receiver with message: Restarting receiver with delay 2000ms: Could not connect: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
17/06/27 16:04:47 INFO RabbitMQReceiver: Closed all RabbitMQ connections
17/06/27 16:04:47 INFO ReceiverSupervisorImpl: Called receiver onStop
17/06/27 16:04:47 INFO ReceiverSupervisorImpl: Deregistering receiver 0
17/06/27 16:04:47 ERROR ReceiverTracker: Deregistered receiver for stream 0: Restarting receiver with delay 2000ms: Could not connect - java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandlerFactory.create(SocketFrameHandlerFactory.java:50)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.newConnection(RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.java:60)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringConnection.init(AutorecoveringConnection.java:99)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:911)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:870)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:692)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.rabbitmq.consumer.Consumer$.org$apache$spark$streaming$rabbitmq$consumer$Consumer$$addConnection(Consumer.scala:269)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.rabbitmq.consumer.Consumer$$anonfun$1.apply(Consumer.scala:251)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.rabbitmq.consumer.Consumer$$anonfun$1.apply(Consumer.scala:251)
        at scala.collection.MapLike$class.getOrElse(MapLike.scala:128)
        at scala.collection.AbstractMap.getOrElse(Map.scala:59)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.rabbitmq.consumer.Consumer$.getChannel(Consumer.scala:251)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.rabbitmq.consumer.Consumer$.apply(Consumer.scala:207)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.rabbitmq.receiver.RabbitMQReceiver$$anonfun$3.apply(RabbitMQInputDStream.scala:60)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.rabbitmq.receiver.RabbitMQReceiver$$anonfun$3.apply(RabbitMQInputDStream.scala:59)
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.rabbitmq.receiver.RabbitMQReceiver.onStart(RabbitMQInputDStream.scala:59)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.startReceiver(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:149)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.start(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverTrackerEndpoint$$anonfun$9.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:597)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverTrackerEndpoint$$anonfun$9.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:587)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$33.apply(SparkContext.scala:1976)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$33.apply(SparkContext.scala:1976)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I've tried as much as I can to troubleshoot, I have checked that there is no firewall or network connectivity issues between the two servers. I have also checked that the credential, IP, Port, Queue, Username, and Password are all correct.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is in rabbitmq log file?

Comment: Nothing is in the log file... the service does not even pick up my connection request. When I used my python script to connect to it, I am able to see these log messages:

=INFO REPORT==== 27-Jun-2017::16:03:01 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.17003.144> (localhost:60769 -> 1.2.3.4:5672)

=WARNING REPORT==== 27-Jun-2017::16:03:03 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.17003.144> (localhost:60769 -> 1.2.3.4:5672):
connection_closed_abruptly

Comment: You need details of the `connection refused` exception. Try to debug the application and check exception's internals.

Comment: Would you be able to provide some suggestions on how I can check the exceptions internals? I've got a remote debug session now using IDEA, and I'm walking through with breakpoints with no real success on catching the connection refused exception.

Comment: Haven't used Java/spark at all, so can't really help you here sorry. Another thing you could try is to analyse traffic on you client node (not on the server) with wireshark and get the "connection refused" response in the clear, it should contain some more information about what is happening. I assume server and client are not on the same machine. Maybe some firewall rules? Check that 5672 port is allowed into the RabbitMQ node. Also, try and connect with python from the node you where you have connection problem. Looks like you tried to connect from localhost only.